# Conversion of integer -> char

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm learning scheme and I stumbled upon this in a textbook:

(integer->char 50) ⇒ #\2

Why does integer->char 50 evaluate to 2? Is it because "50" is too big to be a character, so it just takes the length/number of digits?

Comment: `#\2` is the *digit* '2', not the number 2. You could check your hypothesis about the length by converting 51 (which will be `#\3`) and 100 (which will be `#\d`).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't evaluate to `2`: it evaluates to the *character* `#\2`, which is a completely different thing:

```
> (for ([i (in-range 32 128)])
    (let ([c (integer->char i)])
      (printf "~S: ~S / '~A'~%" i c c)))
32: #\space / ' '
33: #\! / '!'
34: #\" / '"'
35: #\# / '#'
36: #\$ / '$'
37: #\% / '%'
38: #\& / '&'
39: #\' / '''
40: #\( / '('
41: #\) / ')'
42: #\* / '*'
43: #\+ / '+'
44: #\, / ','
45: #\- / '-'
46: #\. / '.'
47: #\/ / '/'
48: #\0 / '0'
49: #\1 / '1'
50: #\2 / '2'
51: #\3 / '3'
52: #\4 / '4'
53: #\5 / '5'
54: #\6 / '6'
55: #\7 / '7'
56: #\8 / '8'
57: #\9 / '9'
58: #\: / ':'
59: #\; / ';'
60: #\< / '<'
61: #\= / '='
62: #\> / '>'
63: #\? / '?'
64: #\@ / '@'
65: #\A / 'A'
66: #\B / 'B'
67: #\C / 'C'
68: #\D / 'D'
69: #\E / 'E'
70: #\F / 'F'
71: #\G / 'G'
72: #\H / 'H'
73: #\I / 'I'
74: #\J / 'J'
75: #\K / 'K'
76: #\L / 'L'
77: #\M / 'M'
78: #\N / 'N'
79: #\O / 'O'
80: #\P / 'P'
81: #\Q / 'Q'
82: #\R / 'R'
83: #\S / 'S'
84: #\T / 'T'
85: #\U / 'U'
86: #\V / 'V'
87: #\W / 'W'
88: #\X / 'X'
89: #\Y / 'Y'
90: #\Z / 'Z'
91: #\[ / '['
92: #\\ / '\'
93: #\] / ']'
94: #\^ / '^'
95: #\_ / '_'
96: #\` / '`'
97: #\a / 'a'
98: #\b / 'b'
99: #\c / 'c'
100: #\d / 'd'
101: #\e / 'e'
102: #\f / 'f'
103: #\g / 'g'
104: #\h / 'h'
105: #\i / 'i'
106: #\j / 'j'
107: #\k / 'k'
108: #\l / 'l'
109: #\m / 'm'
110: #\n / 'n'
111: #\o / 'o'
112: #\p / 'p'
113: #\q / 'q'
114: #\r / 'r'
115: #\s / 's'
116: #\t / 't'
117: #\u / 'u'
118: #\v / 'v'
119: #\w / 'w'
120: #\x / 'x'
121: #\y / 'y'
122: #\z / 'z'
123: #\{ / '{'
124: #\| / '|'
125: #\} / '}'
126: #\~ / '~'
127: #\rubout / ''
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know that it does not convert a numeric value to it's digit, rather it converts the [ascii value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg) to its corresponding character. Eg. the ascii value 50 represents the character `#\2` (digit 2) and 65 represents `#\A` (capital letter A).

You find the [documentation](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_482) in the report:

> procedure:  `(char->integer char)`
> procedure:  `(integer->char n)`
>
> Given a character, char->integer returns an exact integer
> representation of the character. Given an exact integer that is the
> image of a character under char->integer, integer->char returns that
> character.

Scheme has a procedure called [`number->string`](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_sec_6.2.6) which converts a number to a string representation:

```
(number->string 50 10)   ; ==> "50" (base 10 representation)
(number->string #x32 10) ; ==> "50" (base 10 representation)
(number->string 50 16)   ; ==> "32" (hex, base 16)
```